# XML layout doesn't appear

Tags: android, android-studio

I am writing an XML code but it doesn't appear on the layout. What is wrong?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/Number_Activity"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello world"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Copy and paste your XML code here, do not use a picture.

Comment: what's the value of `@string/Number_Activity`?

Comment: @Yousaf The value is Number

Comment: @Xenolion I added it

Comment: I tried to open a new project and nothing changed

Comment: Is it possible you are previewing it only. Have you tried a design tab as well???

Comment: no, I didn't try to design a tab 
but the problem is when I open Android studio and start to design nothin appear I thought that the android studio is stacked then I restart nothing happened 
Opend a new project the same result I got I can't design

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This XML file has no problem, you can not see it because of using not suitable **theme**,
modify styles.xml like this:

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">  //use appropriate theme
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>
```

In design view, you could change theme as fig shown:
[image]

Comment: could you upvote my answer or accept it if its helpful, thanks!